# Regular expression for date having space

Tags: regex

Hi my text string as below

```
May 15 02:50:23
Jun 2 02:50:23
```

i can match perfectly with below regular expression

```
^([A-Z][a-z]{2}) ([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})
```

how i can match below regular expression when there is space before day?
having issues when there is space fore 1 digit date which is having space character below

```
Jun  2 02:50:23
Jun <space>2 02:50:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]{2}) +([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})
# quantifier   __^
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help...extracted from [Regular Expression example](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)

> **Trimming Whitespace** 
>   You can easily trim unnecessary whitespace from
>   the start and the end of a string or the lines in a text file by doing
>   a regex search-and-replace. Search for ^[ \t]+ and replace with
>   nothing to delete leading whitespace (spaces and tabs). Search for [
>   \t]+$ to trim trailing whitespace. Do both by combining the regular
>   expressions into ^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$. Instead of [ \t] which matches a
>   space or a tab, you can expand the character class into [ \t\r\n] if
>   you also want to strip line breaks. Or you can use the shorthand \s
>   instead.

Comment: What this have to do with the question?

Comment: Why not? You can remove the leading space before searching.

Comment: Where did you see leading space in the question?

Comment: Jun <space>2 02:50:23

Comment: This is not a `leading` space.